# Vertical Blue Lines On Windows Boot - Does Boot

Tags: boot, graphics-card, windows-10

About 2 days ago, I booted up windows and when it starts to load, it has blue vertical lines all the way along the screen. This happens up until the windows is done with the loading splash screen, and then it goes black for 5 seconds and then goes to login and it is perfectly fine. Here is what I have tried so far to try and dissolve the problem:

-Check graphics card temp --- It was far below temp, so it was good
-Check monitor... It worked fine with another PC

Anything else I can do to see if it solves it? And also, should I be worried or should I just let it go?

Here are my specs:
CPU: Intel i5-4460
GPU: MSI Radeon R9 390 8GB Gaming
PSU: 750W
RAM: 16 GB
OS: Windowx 10 x64

Comment: Can you provide an image of what exactly you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because my motherboard has a graphical splashscreen on boot. I had just gotten an r9 380x that displayed blue vertical lines whenever the splashscreen is supposed to display.

I had to go into the bios/setup (hit f2 or delete when starting up your pc)

Look for anything that mentions along the lines of "disabling logo" and make sure its set to disabled.

After this it booted fine and loaded the typical boot screen without the motherboard splashscreen (it was replaced by the typical system specs in grey text)

Answer (score -1):

You can remove this minor "scary artifacts" on Windows startup loading screen simply by disabling  fastboot in BIOS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).